# JSON.parse() causes error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0`

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm writing my first application in Node.js. I am trying to read some data from a file where the data is stored in the JSON format.

I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ﻿ in JSON at position 0
>
> at Object.parse (native)

Here is this part of the code:

```
//read saved addresses of all users from a JSON file
fs.readFile('addresses.json', function (err, data) {
    if (data) {
        console.log("Read JSON file: " + data);
        storage = JSON.parse(data);
```

Here is the `console.log` output (and I checked the .json file itself, it's the same):

```
Read JSON file: ﻿{

    "addresses": []

}
```

That seems to me like a correct JSON. Why does `JSON.parse()` fail then?

Comment: Line breaks are not enabled in `JSON.parse` argument

Comment: @MysterX But the syntax error is at position 0? And JSON.parse() doesn't seem to have an argument to enable line breaks.

Comment: you need to set an encoding its because of BOM

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have a strange char at the beginning of the file.

`data.charCodeAt(0) === 65279`

I would recommend:

```
fs.readFile('addresses.json', function (err, data) {
if (data) {
    console.log("Read JSON file: " + data);
    data = data.trim(); 
    //or data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.trim()));
    storage = JSON.parse(data);
 }});
```

Comment: I was having a similar issue and adding `data.trim()` before running `JSON.parse()` fixed it.

Comment: @PrashantTapase `trim` is not necesarilly needed but if you expect that the input for `JSON.parse` may be corrupted by chars that may be filtered out by `trim` then you can apply it.

One could even do it only when it is required:
`try:
   json_data = JSON.parse(data);
catch(ex) {
    json_data = JSON.parse(data.trim());
}`

Comment: why trim is needed!  :) +1 my problem solved. thank you! @bluehipy

Comment: I get `TypeError: data.trim is not a function`. 
Works without it though, after copying the JSON data into a TextEdit (MacOS) file and saving it again as a file.json with utf-8

Answer (score 10):

`JSON.parse()` does not allow trailing commas. So, you need to get rid of it:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

You can find more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: Weird, I don't have a single comma in the file?

Comment: It means this: "addresses": []

Comment: This allows my UTF-16 Little Endian file to be loaded. My program no longer crashes. But it is pure garbage. And I realize I am the one that caused it. By using stringify instead of converting to UTF8. Looping, it had 3,600 key/value pairs. Which is about the same number of characters in my file.

Answer (score 5):

It might be the BOM[[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)].
I have done a test by saving a file with content `{"name":"test"}` with UTF-8 + BOM, and it generated the same error.

```
> JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("a.json"))
SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
```

And based on a suggestion here [[2](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/1918)], you can replace it or drop it before you call `JSON.parse()`.

For example:

```
var storage = {};

fs.readFile('a.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (data) {
        console.log("Read JSON file: " + data);
        console.log(typeof(data))
        storage = JSON.parse(data.trim());
    }
});
```

or

```
var storage = {};
fs.readFile('a.json', function (err, data) {
    if (data) {
        console.log("Read JSON file: " + data);
        console.log(typeof(data))
        storage = JSON.parse(data.toString().trim());
    }
})
```

You can also remove the first 3 bytes (for UTF-8) by using `Buffer.slice()`.

Comment: This left a space after every character in each of my keys. And a space after every character in each of my string values.

Comment: @TamusJRoyce BOM is not of length 3 if another encoding is used.  You can search Wikipedia for "byte order mark" to see all possible BOMs.

Comment: My answer below shows a sample of the UTF-16 output. Removing the question mark icon (how Notepad++ shows the encoding you are mentioning) / byte marker in code doesn't solve the encoding issue.

Answer (score 4):

try it like this

```
fs.readFile('addresses.json','utf-8', function (err, data) {
    if (data) {
        console.log("Read JSON file: " + data);
        storage = JSON.parse(data);
```

its because of the BOM that needs an encoding to be set before reading the file. its been issued in nodejs respository in github

https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/186

Comment: That was my problem. Opening and saving the file as UTF-8 only, worked.

Answer (score 2):

To further explain @Luillyfe's answer:

Ah-ha! `fs.readFileSync("data.json")` returns a Javascript object!

**Edit: Below is incorrect...But summarizes what one might think at first!**

I had through that was a string. So if the file was saved as UTF-8/ascii, it would probably not have an issue? The javascript object returned from readFileSync would convert to a string JSON.parse can parse? No need to call JSON.stringify?

I am using powershell to save the file. Which seems to save the file as UTF-16 (too busy right now to check). So I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0."

However, `JSON.stringify(fs.readFileSync("data.json"))` correctly parses that returned file object into a string JSON can parse.

Clue for me is my json file contents looking like the below (after logging it to the console):

```
�{ " R o o m I D _ L o o k u p " :   [
         {
                 " I D " :     1 0 ,
                 " L o c a t i o n " :     " f r o n t " ,
                 " H o u s e " :     " f r o n t r o o m "
         }
}
```

That doesn't seem like something a file would load into a string...

Incorrect being (this does not crash...but instead converts the json file to jibberish!):

```
const jsonFileContents = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(fs.readFileSync("data.json")));
```

I can't seem to find this anywhere. But makes sense!

**Edit: Um... That object is just a buffer. Apologies for the above!**

Solution:

```
const fs = require("fs");

function GetFileEncodingHeader(filePath) {
    const readStream = fs.openSync(filePath, 'r');
    const bufferSize = 2;
    const buffer = new Buffer(bufferSize);
    let readBytes = 0;

    if (readBytes = fs.readSync(readStream, buffer, 0, bufferSize, 0)) {
        return buffer.slice(0, readBytes).toString("hex");
    }   

    return "";
}

function ReadFileSyncUtf8(filePath) {
    const fileEncoding = GetFileEncodingHeader(filePath);
    let content = null;

    if (fileEncoding === "fffe" || fileEncoding === "utf16le") {
        content = fs.readFileSync(filePath, "ucs2"); // utf-16 Little Endian
    } else if (fileEncoding === "feff" || fileEncoding === "utf16be") {
        content = fs.readFileSync(filePath, "uts2").swap16(); // utf-16 Big Endian
    } else {
        content = fs.readFileSync(filePath, "utf8");
    }

    // trim removes the header...but there may be a better way!
    return content.toString("utf8").trimStart();
}

function GetJson(filePath) {
    const jsonContents = ReadFileSyncUtf8(filePath);
    console.log(GetFileEncodingHeader(filePath));

    return JSON.parse(jsonContents);
}
```

Usage:

```
GetJson("data.json");
```

Note: I don't currently have a need for this to be async yet. Add another answer if you can make this async!

Comment: I have added this as a bug to node: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/23033. Give it an upvote there if you believe this is worth doing.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_textdecoder_decode_input_options may have a feature to solve the above

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by TamusJRoyce I ended up using the util.TextDecoder class to come up with a robust way to read both UTF-8 (without BOM) and UTF-8 (with BOM). Here's the snippit, assuming that file input.json is UTF-8 (with or without BOM) and contains valid JSON.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');

const rawdata = fs.readFileSync('input.json');
const textDecoder = new util.TextDecoder('utf-8');
const stringData = textDecoder.decode(rawdata);
const objects = JSON.parse(stringData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const myConsole = new console.Console(fs.createWriteStream('./output.json'));
myConsole.log(object);
```

This will create an output file with all the output which can been triggered through `console.log(object)`.

This is the easiest way to convert the `console.log()` output into a  file.`